# Python array and function

Tags: python, list

I have a list 'map' and I want to replace all elements by the respectives output values ​​of a function "counterPosition" that acts on each position of the initial array, something like that:

```
map[0][0] = counterPosition(0,0)
map[0][1] = counterPosition(0,1)
...
```

Doing one by one like that I can get the answer, but when I try something like that:

```
 for x in range (len(map)):
    for y in range (len(map)):
        map[x][y] = counterPosition(x,y)
```

It doesn't work... Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

```
def counterPosition(x, y):
    bombs = 0
    for i in range(x-1, x+2):
        for j in range(y-1, y+2):
            if i<0 or j<0: continue
            elif map[i][j] == True:
                bombs += 1
    return bombs

map = [[True, False, False, False, False, True],
         [False, False, False, False, False, True],
         [True, True, False, True, False, True],
         [True, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, True, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

The error is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Do you have a numpy `array`, or a standard python `list` (nested) instead?

Comment: map =   [[True, False, False, False, False, True],
         [False, False, False, False, False, True],
         [True, True, False, True, False, True],
         [True, False, False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, True, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False]]

Comment: That is a `list`, not an `array`.

Comment: "It' doesn't work..." is not a very elaborate problem description. Do you get an error? Which python version are you using? You realize, that you are using a) a list (not an array) b) you override the builtin `map` function.

Comment: As a side note: It's a bad idea to name a variable `map`, as that's a built-in function (and one that might even be directly useful to your problem…).

Comment: Sorry for the mistake about the list/array, I don't speak english very well... I made some edits on the problem so you can have a better view of waht's happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there

```
for x in range (len(map)):
    for y in range(len(map[x])):
        map[x][y] = counterPosition(x,y)
```

**Update**: The original code you gave will only run as long as your map is square, but this *is* the case for the data you provided. Looking at your sample data and updated code, the actual error is coming from your `counterPosition` function. Actually there are two problems.

**1.**  In your `counterPosition` function you accessing elements that are out of range. This is printed as part of the error message right above `IndexError:...` - it's a good idea to read these messages carefully and include it in your post. If you pass in `x=5,y-5` then the function will try and access `map[6][6]`. The "correct" code should be something like

```
def counterPosition(x, y):
    bombs = 0
    for i in range(x-1, x+2):
        for j in range(y-1, y+2):
            # check bounds:
            if 0 <= i < len(map) and 0 <= j < len(map[i]):
                if map[i][j] == True:
                    bombs += 1
    return bombs
```

**2.** The second problem is that `counterPosition` *expects* `map` to contain boolean elements, however you are returning an integer from `counterPosition` and assigning that to `map[x][y]`. So the next time round `map` will contain integer values. Without seeing the rest of your project, I think what you want are two separate multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: ...and Mr. E's implementation works fine for me with your data, and an arbitrary counterPosition function, so it's something else you're doing wrong